# I can't get data stream from firestore how do I fix this ؟

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

**I tried fetching the data without using the `StreamBuilder` and all the data was fetched successfully but when I used the `StreamBuilder` it didn't work**

[image]

```
StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('chats/IClRN96vdYSpdtfT4PZh/messeges').snapshots(),
          builder: (ctx , snap) {
            if(snap.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
            }
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snap.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Text('Text Chat messeges'),
          ));
          })
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `snap.data.documents.length` with `snap.data.docs.length`

Comment: Nothing has changed

Answer (score 0):

**add `AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>` to snap**

```
 StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('chats/IClRN96vdYSpdtfT4PZh/messeges').snapshots(),
          builder: (ctx , AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snap) {
            if(snap.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
            }
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snap.data!.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Text('Text Chat messeges'),
          ));
          })
```

**And before the `documents` put `!` **